# Shiny - How to disable user input in numericInput used in uiOutput

Tags: shiny, shiny-reactivity

my code:-

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Find square of x"),
    numericInput("x","x:",5),
    uiOutput("y")
)

server <- function(input, output){
     output$y <- renderUI({
          numericInput("y","Square of x:",input$x * input$x)
     })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

In this app user can change the value of output `"Square of x"`. Is there any way this can be prevented (means user input can be disabled in output).

Or anything like if a user modifies output `"Square of x"` than input `"x"` also get change accordingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, we can use `shinyjs` for that:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  titlePanel("Find square of x"),
  numericInput("x","x:",5),
  numericInput("y","Square of x:",NULL)
)

server <- function(input, output,session){

  observeEvent(input$x,{
    updateNumericInput(session, "y", value = input$x * input$x)
    disable("y")
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]